# GDI handle types

Tags: winapi, gdi, memory-leaks

I'm currently trying to track down a GDI handle leak. I am currently using [GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) to track it down. The tool divides the GDI objects into categories Pen, ExtPen, Bitmap, Font, Palette, Region, DC, Metafile DC, Enhanced Metafile DC, and Other GDI. These categories are summed in a column called GDI Total. Ontop of that, there's a column called All GDI. It is in this column I am detecting the leak.

As I don't have the source code for the tool, I can't see what's really going on. Did the author of the tool miss a handle type? It looks like it. I do know there *is* a leak, because some users report that they are shown the infamous dialog *A required resource was* (end of text). It may take weeks for the dialog to show up, so I'm pretty sure it isn't a DC.

Any ideas on how to track this down would be much appreciated! As I have a limited budget, thousand dollar tools are out of the question. Debugging hooks into GDI would suffice, as I don't mind doing detective work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently, [GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) thinks that icons fall under the unknown category. The problem was an icon being loaded and attached to an object. The object was not setup to auto delete the icon upon destruction. E-mailing the author of said tool...

Comment: There are some object types lacking from GDI View, but Icon is a USER object, not GDI.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a similar problem and I used Task Manager - asked it to show GDI handles count for each process and stepped over the program code to see where the handles count unexpectedly increases and fails to decrease back. It took some time, but finally using divide-and-conquer I found the error.

Comment: I really recommend the GDIView program, as it will show you the various type of GDI objects that are allocated. Also, it gives you a snapshot/diff mechanism, so that you get a difference measurement between two points in time. Unfortunately it doesn't recognize icon resources properly.